# Jquery get value

Tags: jquery

I am set returnStatus value in success. But not show value. If I set returnStatus value before return(returnStatus), it is work. How can I set value in success and use it?

Thanks for Answers.

My Jquery Code;

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.MubsisAjax = function(options){
        var defaults = {            
            Tabs        : false
        } 

        var returnStatus = ""; 

        var jqxhr =  $.ajax({
            type        : "POST",
            url         : "post.asp",
            //cache     : true,     
            //ifModified    : true, 
                success     : function(event){
                    returnStatus = "value"
                }


            });
    //returnStatus = "value"
    return(returnStatus)

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is really a javascript beginner question, I don't have enough energy to make an answer here.

Comment: @Drasill: and yet you can write a comment...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Comment: Thanks for answers. But problem is not resolved. I want to make, If post is succces set one variable and use it. I write a json this value.

Answer (score 0):

it can't work because function is returning imediatelly, not waiting for ajax's response. You can call  your function in success: callback